# Give a Form a Popup window

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, aspx

I would like to use a SharePoint Designer to show a form (DispForm.aspx) as a popup instead of opening into a new tab.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to re-invent the wheel in SharePoint Designer. Adjust the list settings > Advanced settings > Launch form in dialog > Yes

Answer (score 3):

No need to do this via SharePoint Designer and you should try to

> Open List > List Settings > Advance Settings > scroll down to dialogs
>    check Yes

as shown below.

[image]